# chef-client installed, but chef-client --version shows error Could not find chef (>= 0) amongst

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to update the chef-client version and verify it by running chef-client --version.  The update seems to work, but chef-client --version shows error Could not find chef (>= 0) amongst ...

Comment: How did you install Chef? Through rubygems? You shouldn't do that. Chef suggests that you [download](https://downloads.chef.io/) a so-called _omnibus_ package that also includes Ruby - in order to avoid fiddling with different Ruby versions like you do.

Answer (score 3):

Don't install chef client using gems. Install the Chefdk package instead:

https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/

Much much simpler.

Note of caution if you are using rvm and chefdk together make sure and configure the former to use the system ruby, otherwise chef won't be able to pick up the embedded instance of ruby that ships with the chefdk package.

```
rvm use system
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution

$ rvm use system

then the

$ chef-client --version

works properly

Comment: As stated above, Chef and RVM are only marginally compatible at the best of times. rbenv, chruby, or not using any of them is preferable.